# Visualization of vector fields

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields

The definition of a vector field in the standard multivariable calculus setting is the following

> Given a subset $U \in \mathbb{R}^n$, a vector field is represented by a vector-valued function $f:U \to \Bbb R^n$ which is continuous if the component functions are.

It's been bugging me that the way these are presented is essentially as if the output of $f$ is attached to the input of $f$, but that doesn't really make sense in my mind.

For example let $U \subset \Bbb R^2$ and define $f:U \to \Bbb R^2$ as $f(x,y)=(1,2).$ The visualization for this map is done by attaching the vector $( 1, 2)$ to every input $(x,y)$ for $f$, but I have hard time believing that this is true. This map simply maps each point $(x,y)$ to the vector $(1,2)$ starting from the origin. Or I could simply think about this as a constant map in which everything is mapped to the point $(1,2) \in \Bbb R^2$.

What is wrong with my interpretation? Any clarification for this would be nice. I might have missed something very obvious here.

Comment: Vectors are defined by their length and direction, not their position in space relative to some reference point. In $\mathbb R^2$, the vector from $(0,0)$ to $(1,0)$ is the same as the vector from $(1,0)$ to $(2,0)$. Both have length $1$ and both make an angle of $0^\circ$ relative to the positive $x$-axis.

Comment: In this very specific case, you could consider the graph-mapping of $f$, defined as $\Gamma_f:U\to U\times\Bbb{R}^n$, $\Gamma_f(x)=(x,f(x))$. Now, we can keep the interpretation that $\Gamma_f(x)$ is a vector at the point $x$. The output $(x,f(x))$ having $x$ as the first component tells us it is a "vector based at $x$" i.e the **field** in "vector field", and the second part $f(x)$ keeps track of the vector part, i.e the **vector** in "vector field". This definition only works when $U\subset\Bbb{R}^n$ is open. In general we need to define manifolds and tangent bundles to define vector fields.

Comment: However, if you're exclusively going to be working with open subsets of $\Bbb{R}^n$ for the time-being, then it is simply out of convenience that one works directly with $f$ rather than $\Gamma_f$ (because it's simpler to write down, and also there's a bijective correspondence between the two, and also $f$ and $\Gamma_f$ have same degree of smoothness).

Answer (score 1):

Your interpretation is totally right and better than that definition. Vector fields attach, to every point $(x,y)$, a vector originated in $(x,y)$. This is the correct geometric way to picture it, but you can see that since the "codomain" depends on the point $(x,y)$, you can't define it as a map (maps have fixed, definite codomains).

One trick to solve it is to define the space $T_{(x,y)}\mathbb{R}^2$ of vectors with origin at $(x,y)$ (this is called the *tangent space* at $(x,y)$) and then define $TU$ as the disjoint union of all the $T_{(x,y)}\mathbb{R}^2$ with $(x,y)$ varying in $U$. This is the space all vectors with origin in any point of $U$. That way, a vector field is a map $f:U \rightarrow TU$ such that $f(x,y)$ belongs to $T_{(x,y)}\mathbb{R}^2$ for every $(x,y)\in U$.

Since every $T_{(x,y)}\mathbb{R}^2$ is a vector space of dimension $2$, they are all isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$, and that is why usually there is no distinction made between them, and a vector field is just defined as a map to $\mathbb{R}^2$. The concept of tangent space and of the *tangent bundle* $TU$ is introduced in differential geometry, where there's no natural isomorphism between each tangent space and $\mathbb{R}^n$.